# How to create a photo gallery with slideshow effect of the images placed in server folder using jsp/servlet/javascript

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp

I need to create slideshow of the images which are in server.These images would be changing as the user uploads. I need this using jsp/javascript/servlet/ajax

Comment: Please explain your problem a little more detailed. Is it with the slide show at all or don't you how to handle the uploads? Should a open/running (inside a browser) slide show change when user uploads take place?

Answer (score 1):

Generally when the page loads, the slideshow code already has a list of the available files. It would need to use AJAX to poll the server periodically to determine if this list has changed (a user had uploaded a file). Typically you'd just replace the array or string holding the list of files in the AJAX call.

The server-side code just needs to supply the list of files in a folder in a format the slideshow expects.

Here's a [collection of different slideshows](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/18/30-best-solutions-for-image-galleries-slideshows-lightboxes/) you can grab and modify for this purpose.